# "INTERSECT" columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL sentences, with the form `SELECT sth FROM table WHERE condition`. One of them is defined in the privacy rules of my system, and represents the data that the current user have access to. The other one is introduced by the current user, that want to retrieve data from the database. So I want to "intersect" the columns of these sentences, and only retrieve the ones that the user is asking for and have access to.

For example, let's say I have in my policy `SELECT * FROM table`, which grants access to everything, and the user inputs `SELECT id, name FROM table`. In this case, I'd like to send `SELECT id, name FROM table` to the database.

Another example, if I have in my policy set `SELECT id, name, phone FROM table`, and the user prompts `SELECT name, location FROM table`, I'd like to send `SELECT name FROM table` to the database.

**Is there any from in SQL syntax to get this?**

The part of `WHERE condition` related to the rows is easier, and I think I can manage. But I don't know how to work with columns.

My approach right now consists of splitting the query string on my .js, but it's messy and I'd like to do it through SQL syntax.

Comment: `inner join` what the user requested and what they are allowed.

Comment: how? I don't really know how to use `INNER JOIN` properly

Comment: On reading again, it seems like you're asking for column-level access control, not row-level, so I don't have any ideas off the top of my head for that.

Comment: You want to intersect not resultsets but output columns (i.e. you want to intersect output structures, metadata). None DBMS have instruments for this.

Comment: This should be handled by application or by database engine, not SQL. Only dynamic query can change unpredictable columns in resultset, because in static SQL identifiers and data are different entities.

Comment: You can check [database documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/grant-tables.html#grant-tables-tables-priv-columns-priv) not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing what you specifically want is hard in SQL.  Why?  Because a SQL query returns a *fixed* set of columns.  So removing columns based on user access lists is not built into SQL.

You do have options.  One option is to use views instead of a separate table for the access.  For instance, everyone, perhaps, could have access to:

```
create view as v_table_names 
    select name
    from employees;
```

But only limited folks could have:

```
create view as v_table_names_salaries
    select name, salary
    from employees;
```

Users would only have access to the views and not to the underlying tables.

Another alternative is to `NULL` out the columns.  This would be something like:

```
select (case when ca.access_columns like '%[name]%' then name end) as name,
       (case when ca.access_columns like '%[salary]%' then salary end) as salary 
from employees e left join
     column_access ca
     on ca.table_name = 'employees' and
        ca.user_id = ?
```

This assumes that the "access" table has column lists stored as "[name][salary]".

I don't really recommend this approach because it is quite brittle -- changes to the data model take some work to implement correctly.  However, it seems closest to what you are describing.

MySQL also offers column-level permissions.  However, I think it just rejects a query that tries to access unpermitted columns.

Comment: Thanks! I think views are what I needed. Thank you so much.